# why I'm getting multiple entities as one

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

> I'm using a Custom NER model(CRF based) for NER tagging. but the problem is whenever multiple entities separated by punctuation or any stopword occur in test data. it tags whole as one entity.

for example-
for "India, china" it produce
**(u'India', u'B-LOC'),(u',', u'I-LOC'),(u'china', u'I-LOC')**
and for "india and australia" it produce
**(u'india', u'B-LOC'),(u'and', u'I-LOC'),(u'australia', u'I-LOC')**

> I have not removed any stopwords or punctuation from my training dataset and they are labled as 'O'. But why I'm getting these punchuation and stopwords that occur between two entities as part of single entity?

here is my property file and dataset that I used in my model training-

**Property File(ner.prop)**

```
 trainFile=Clean_Data.tsv
 serializeTO=ner-model_cleanGazette_full.ser.gz
 map = word=0,answer=1,tag=2
 useClassFeature=true
 useWord=true
 useNGrams=true
 noMidNGrams=true
 qnSize=10
 entitySubclassification=IOB2
 retainEntitySubclassification=true
 maxNGramLeng=6
 usePrev=true
 useNext=true
 useSequences=true
 usePrevSequences=true
 useTypeSeqs=true
 useTypeSeqs2=true
 useTypeySequences=true
 wordShape=chris2useLC
 useDisjunctive=true
 useGazettes=true
 gazette=gazetta.txt
 sloppyGazette=true
```

**[Kaggle Dataset used](https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus#ner_dataset.csv)(Clean_Data.tsv)**

```
**Word    ner     pos**
Thousands   O   NNS
of  O   IN
demonstrators   O   NNS
have    O   VBP
marched O   VBN
through O   IN
London  B-LOC   NNP
to  O   TO
protest O   VB
```

> what else can I add or remove to overcome this problem?